# Class or interface expected for SMS service?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service, development-environment

I want to create a simple service, but when i try to call my ServiceSMS.java class in the manifest, it says me that "class or interface expected".

My manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.romain.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service android:name="ServiceSMS"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.romain.myapplication.MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver class="com.exemple.romain.SMSReceiver" android:name=".SMSReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.romain.myapplication.ReadTheMessage">
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

</manifest>
```

And my class ServiceSMS :

```
package com.example.romain.myapplication;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ServiceSMS extends IntentService {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "ServiceSMS";

    public ServiceSMS() {    
        super("ServiceSMS");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        String dataString = workIntent.getDataString();
        // ... 
    }
}
```

here my SMS Receiver :

```
package com.example.romain.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import static java.util.Locale.FRANCE;


public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    static TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String phoneNumber = null;
        String ACTION_RECEIVE_SMS = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_RECEIVE_SMS)) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < pdus.length; j++)  {  messages[j] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[j]);  }  if (messages.length > -1) {
                final String messageBody = messages[0].getMessageBody();
                phoneNumber = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            }
            String test = "Tu as reçu un nouveau sms de "+phoneNumber;
            Intent speechIntent = new Intent();
            speechIntent.setClass(context, ReadTheMessage.class);
            speechIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE", test);
            speechIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            context.startActivity(speechIntent);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int i) {

        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String s) {
                System.out.println("Fait");


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String s) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Where is my bug please?

Comment: Without seeing your Android project's structure it's hard to say where the error is. I'm guessing it might be related to relative path like `android:name=".ServiceSMS"`, or that you haven't started your **ServiceSMS** `Service` from your `BroadcastReceiver`. Edit your post with your project's structure, or at least show us the codes of the `SMSReceiver` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have number of problems here.

Change

```
  <receiver class="com.exemple.romain.SMSReceiver" android:name=".SMSReceiver">
```

to

```
<receiver class="com.example.romain.SMSReceiver" android:name=".SMSReceiver">
```

You have **exemple** instead of **example**

And you need to put

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

before `<activity>`

And change your service declaration as

```
 <service android:name="com.example.romain.ServiceSMS"/>
```

Comment: anything change, the same problem is here :/

Comment: Just handsome, I can compile and run my app but the error stay here

Comment: Yep problem resolved but I can't publish screenshots I don't have 10 reputation.

Thank you Nabin !

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
<service android:name=".myapplication.ServiceSMS"/>
```

in manifest

Comment: same problem when I try your correction.
Thanks for your answer